# getting Backbone collection size?

Tags: backbone.js

I've a Backbone Collection

```
var users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'https://localhost:2222/users',
    model: User
});
```

In Controller I need to get no of users.

```
var usersList = new Users();
      usersList .fetch({
        beforeSend: CommonUtils.sendAuthentication,
        data: $.param({ group: group.id})
});
```

I tried usersList.length it returns 0 but console shows some data in 'usersList'

[image]

I logged

```
console.log(usersList);
console.log(usersList.length);
```

in 'child' object length shows as 0 but inside that length is 4.

Comment: You may want to pass a [success callback](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) to the fetch function and get the count there?

Comment: Keep in mind that `console.log` often puts a live reference into the console so what you see in the console isn't always what was around when you called `console.log`. Try `console.log(usersList.toJSON())` and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are counting the Length after the `fetch` has come in? Remember that fetching takes some time and your javascript will not wait for it.

Answer (score 1):

By default Backbone **`.fetch()`** makes **asynchronous** HTTP (Ajax) request which does not finish right away, that is why you have to use **`success`** and **`error`** callback functions which will be fired accordingly after **`.fetch()`** returns a response from the server.

Both **`success`** and **`error`** receives fetched collection, server response and option objects.

*Simple example:*

```
usersList.fetch({
    success: function(collection, response, options){
        console.log(collection.length);

        // Method which would use your fetched colletion
        myFancyMethodUsingCollection(collection); 
    },

    error: function(collection, response, options){

    }
});
```

---

To expand, Backbone `collection.fetch([options])` is based on `Backbone.sync(method, model, [options])` which is based on `jQuery.ajax` which by default performs asynchronous requests.

Behavior of **`.fetch()`** can be modified by passing options to the method.

Options may contain settings for Backbone *(for ex.: silent fetch which does not fire collection `changed` event and so on.)* or jQuery.ajax settings.

Note that using  `async: false` option is discouraged by jQuery.

> Synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any
>   actions while the request is active. As of jQuery 1.8, the use of
>   async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the
>   success/error/complete callback options instead.

- [Backbone.Collection.fetch()](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch)
- [Backbone.sync()](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync)
- [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)